# Як перекласти термін "Engine" (базова програма, на базі якої створюється конкретна реалізація гри, сайту)

Tags: терміни, from-english, переклад

Чи є якійсь усталене слово, що відповідає англійському ***Engine***, що використовується для позначення базової програми, на основі якої створюється якийсь інший продукт.

Наприклад:

- гра на основі Unreal Engine (тобто використовується система інтерфейсу і дизайну рівнів гри від гри Unreal);
- гра на основі Quake Engine (відповідно гра на основі Quake);
- сайт на основі Google App Engine.

У російській використовувалося слово "движок", але спроби перекласти його як "двигунець" мають швидше комічний ефект.

Comment: Є, *рушій*. [Вікіпедія так оговорить](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%80%D1%83%D1%88%D1%96%D0%B9). Хоча програмісти часто кажуть *двіжок*, але гадаю це під впливом російськомовної термінології.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Найпоширенішим варіантом можна вважати переклад "рушій":

- його пропонує [Вікіпедія](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%80%D1%83%D1%88%D1%96%D0%B9);
- словосполучення "пошуковий рушій" наявне у [документації](http://help.opera.com/Windows/12.10/uk/search.html) веб-оглядача Opera;
- словосполучення "ігровий рушій" використовується на тематичних сайтах про комп'ютерні ігри (див. [тут](http://playua.net/anonsovano-igrovyj-rushij-cryengine-5/) або [тут](http://uk.wikis.wikia.com/wiki/The_Elder_Scrolls_Wiki_(uk.elderscrolls)))
- "рушій" зустрічається у локалізованій документації проекту KDE ([Reconq](https://userbase.kde.org/Rekonq/uk#.D0.A0.D1.83.D1.88.D1.96.D0.B9_WebKit), [KHTML](https://userbase.kde.org/Glossary/uk#KHTML), [WebKit](https://userbase.kde.org/Glossary/uk#WebKit), [KJS](https://userbase.kde.org/Glossary/uk#KJS)), також словосполучення "рушій даних" у розділі новин на [kde.org](https://www.kde.org/announcements/4.3/index-uk.php)

Comment: Статистика вживання `рушій` vs. `двигун` не на стороні `рушія`.

Comment: @sashaeve, Ви маєте на увазі саме в цьому сенсі чи взагалі? Бо я жодного разу не чув слово «двигун» в цьому сенсі.

Comment: Саме в контексті цього питання. Нижче є статистика вживань і посилання, які говорять про часте використання саме "двигун сайту".

Comment: Можете ще додати, що його системно використовує KDE.

Comment: рушії показу HTML: [KHTML](https://userbase.kde.org/Glossary/uk#KHTML), [WebKit](https://userbase.kde.org/Glossary/uk#WebKit); рушій JS - [KJS](https://userbase.kde.org/Glossary/uk#KJS)

Answer (score 4):

Оскільки дві версії були сформульовані, вирішив зібрати статистику по двигунах та рушіях. Використання **пошуковиків** для порівняння статистики у загальному випадку **не дає правильних чисел** (це тільки оцінка, яка може в декілька разів відрізнятися від реальних значень), але коли результатів небагато і пошукова система дозволяє продивитися всі сторінки з результатами (а не тільки перші 100 сторінок), тоді ці результати більш достовірні. (Тобто у разі використання Google більше 1000 *реальних* результатів перевірити неможливо).

Крім того, перший пошук при переході на останню сторінку дає попередження що пошук не включав схожі результати і щоб включити їх треба перейти по посиланню "repeat the search with the omitted results included." Тільки після цього можна подивитися на справжні числа.

Отже, пошук по словосполученню

- [*"двигун сайту"*](https://www.google.com.ua/?q=%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BD%20%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D1%83#q=%22%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BD%20%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D1%83%22&start=171&filter=0) (зверніть увагу на лапки), дає **181** сайт.
- "двигун сайта" - ще **112** (разом 293).
- [*"рушій сайту"*](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=%22%D1%80%D1%83%D1%88%D1%96%D0%B9%20%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D1%83%22&start=40&filter=0), дає **45** сайтів.
- "рушій сайта" - ще **102** (разом 147).

Але! Пошук по словосполученню

- [*"двигун Unreal"*](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=%22%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BD%20Unreal%22&start=40&filter=0), дає **41** сайт,
- а [*"рушій Unreal"*](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=%22%D1%80%D1%83%D1%88%D1%96%D0%B9%20unreal%22&start=168&filter=0), дає **187** сайтів.

Таким чином, схоже що сайти будують на основі "двигуна", а ігри використовують "рушій". Хоча, звісно для отримання точних результатів потрібні більш детальні дослідження.

---

Щодо неточності попередніх оцінок:

Для словосполучення *"двигун торгівлі"* гугл на першій сторінці оцінював кількість посилань у 7940, а при реальному проходженні по сторінках вийшло 368 результатів - тобто початкова помилка у 20 разів!

*"рушій торгівлі"*: оцінка "приблизно 1540", реально 225. Тобто "на око" різниця між словосполученнями у 5 разів, а реально у 1,6 раз.

Comment: [Порівняння](https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?geo=UA&q=%D1%80%D1%83%D1%88%D1%96%D0%B9%20%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D1%83,%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BD%20%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D1%83) `рушій сайту` і `двигун сайту` через google trends не дав результату, оскільки немає достатньої кількості даних. Якщо порівнювати `рушій` і `двигун` в розділі "Інтернет і комунікація", то маємо значну [перевагу](https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?cat=13&geo=UA&q=%D1%80%D1%83%D1%88%D1%96%D0%B9,%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BD) `двигуна`.

Comment: Спробував шукати "рушій гри" (377) та "двигун гри" (193) - схоже що половина сторінок, що використовують"двигун гри" - автоматично перекладені (гугл плей і т.і., вони мають таке: "Двигун гри .. Чарівна Мотоспорт Гонки. В.Н.: [...] 443 візит. Флеш гра Самурай падіння в бою Флеш гра Падіння самурая .. У цій грі цікавою і весело"). "Рушій гри" - використовує купа статей у Вікіпедії (ще знайшов "гральний рушій").

Answer (score 4):

Хоча питання про переклад єдиним усталеним словом, я все ж наведу варіанти контекстних перекладів (залежних від того, рушій чого саме), що використовуються в програмному забезпеченні:

- Двигун:

  - бекенд-~ *<sub>[Drupal](//localize.drupal.org/translate/languages/uk/translate?search=engine&limit=50).</sub>*
- Засіб:

  - пошуку *<sub>[MS](//www.microsoft.com/Language/en-US/Search.aspx?sString=engine&langID=uk-ua).</sub>*
- Машина:

  - пошукова ~ *<sub>[Drupal](//localize.drupal.org/translate/languages/uk/translate?search=engine&limit=50).</sub>*
- Механізм:

  - банку файлів *<sub>[MS](//www.microsoft.com/Language/en-US/Search.aspx?sString=engine&langID=uk-ua);</sub>*
  - рекомендацій *<sub>[Drupal](//localize.drupal.org/translate/languages/uk/translate?search=engine&limit=50).</sub>*
- Модуль:

  - <без контексту>, ~ для протоколу, репозиторія, синхронізації, сценарію, фільтрації *<sub>[MS](//www.microsoft.com/Language/en-US/Search.aspx?sString=engine&langID=uk-ua).</sub>*
- Обробник:

  - адаптер-~, баз даних, завдань, індексу/індексів, мовлення, потоку даних, рухів, синтезу, сховища, сценаріїв *<sub>[MS](//www.microsoft.com/Language/en-US/Search.aspx?sString=engine&langID=uk-ua).</sub>*
- Рушій:

  - <без контексту>, <в будь-якому контексті> *<sub>[KDE](//l10n.kde.org/team-infos.php?teamcode=uk);</sub>*
  - пошуку *<sub>[Drupal](//localize.drupal.org/translate/languages/uk/translate?search=engine&limit=50).</sub>*
- Система:

  - пошукова ~ *<sub>[Chromium](//translations.launchpad.net/chromium-browser/translations/+pots/chromium-browser/uk/+translate?batch=50&search=engine), [Drupal](//localize.drupal.org/translate/languages/uk/translate?search=engine&limit=50), [MS](//www.microsoft.com/Language/en-US/Search.aspx?sString=engine&langID=uk-ua);</sub>*
  - прийняття рішень *<sub>[MS](//www.microsoft.com/Language/en-US/Search.aspx?sString=engine&langID=uk-ua);</sub>*
  - рекомендацій *<sub>[Drupal](//localize.drupal.org/translate/languages/uk/translate?search=engine&limit=50).</sub>*
- Служба:

  - пошуку, розподілу за рівнями *<sub>[MS](//www.microsoft.com/Language/en-US/Search.aspx?sString=engine&langID=uk-ua).</sub>*
- Ядро:

  - <без контексту>, бази даних, інсталяції *<sub>[MS](//www.microsoft.com/Language/en-US/Search.aspx?sString=engine&langID=uk-ua).</sub>*

Answer (score 2):

**Двигун**

Цей варіант широко розповсюджений серед ІТ спеціалістів. На відміну від *рушія*, який рухає чимось, *двигун* - щось, завдяки чому сайт працює, його ключовий компонент. Пошук в Google покаже велику кількість результатів за [запитом](https://www.google.com.ua/?q=%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BD%20%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D1%83) ***"двигун сайту"***.

**Конструктор**

Якщо використовуються системи, що дозволяють легко компонувати різні модулі та функціональність. Наприклад, Wordpress можна назвати *конструктором сайтів*.

**Система управління контентом**

Якщо ключова задача системи - робота з контентом, то вживають саме такий переклад.