# Як правильно - велобіг чи біговел? Інші варіанти?

Tags: одним-словом, вибір-слова

Як правильно називається порівняно новий вид дитячого транспорту - велосипед без педалей:

[image: Велобіг чи біговел]

Пошук у гуглі дає майже однакову кількість результатів:

- Велобіг - 196 сторінок
- Біговел - 197 сторінок

Таке враження що це сторінки магазинів, які вказують обидва варіанти про всяк випадок.

Чи рівноцінні обидва слова? Чи є інший варіант назви цього транспортного засобу?

---

Через згадку Yellow Sky про Laufmaschine знайшов статтю в англійській вікі [Balance Bicycle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balance_bicycle), а з неї - посилання на українську статтю [Біговел](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D1%96%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BB) з шести рядків. У ній вказані ще такі варіанти назви цього транспортного засобу:

> відомий як **бігове́л**, **велобі́г**, **велосамока́т**, **велока́т**, **велохі́д**, **велоке́тт**, використовуються також англійські назви **балансба́йк** або **ранба́йк**, або німецька **лауфра́д**

Але російська версія статті [Беспедальный велосипед](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%B4), в декілька разів більша за обсягом має такий список:

> известен как **бегове́л**, **велобе́г**, **велосамока́т**, **велока́т**, **велохо́д**, **велоке́тт**, используются также английские названия **балансба́йк** или **ранба́йк**, либо немецкое **лауфра́д**

Що наводить на певні роздуми: чи є український список справжнім, чи просто скалькованим з російської статті.

Основне питання, тим не менш лишається тим самим - який варіант є найбільш уживаним?

Comment: Здається, це нове поняття, яке ще не зійшлося до единого найпоширенішого слова. Обидва слова, здається, утворені цілком за принципами українського словотвору. Та й навіть найдавніші поняття часто дозволяють метатезу: [ведмідь](http://sum.in.ua/s/vedmidj) і [медвідь](http://sum.in.ua/s/medvidj), [капосний](http://sum.in.ua/s/kaposnyj) і [пакосний](http://sum.in.ua/s/pakosnyj), [небокрай](http://sum.in.ua/s/krajnebo) і [крайнебо](http://sum.in.ua/s/nebokraj) — хоча, здається, ці три паре все ж мають більш усталене слово в кожній.

Comment: @Sasha - Насправді найперший в світі велосипед був саме таким, без педалей, ногами відштовхувалися від землі, запатентовано в 1818 році. Він тоді називався Laufmaschine, «бігомашина» або Draisine «дрезина» на честь винахідника, який звався Карл Драйс.

Comment: @YellowSky, ну, так, але, як сучасне явище, в Україну він прийшов лише в 2010-х (масово).

Answer (score 6):

Англійською такі велосипеди [звуться](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balance_bicycle) *balance bicycle* або *run bike*. Калькою з останнього є вже згадане *велобіг / біговел*, а також *біговий велосипед* ([1 910 знаходжень у Ґуглі](https://www.google.com.ua/search?client=opera&q=%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81*%20%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%B4&sourceid=opera&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8#lr=lang_uk&tbs=lr:lang_1uk&q=%22%D0%B1%D1%96%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%B4%22&*)). Та є й калька з першого, це [*баланс-велосипед*](https://www.google.com.ua/search?client=opera&q=%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81*%20%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%B4&sourceid=opera&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8#lr=lang_uk&tbs=lr:lang_1uk&q=%22%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%20%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%B4%22&*), ця назва часто пишеться як два окремі слова, без дефісу (кількість знаходжень у Ґуґлі порахувати проблематично).

Отже, існує як мінімум чотири назви для цього виду дитячого транспорту, або й п’ять, якщо рахувати варіянти з дефісом та без нього, обирати є з чого.

Answer (score 4):

Груба статистика пошуку у Google по назвах транспортних засобів (нюанси використання Google описував у [відповіді про переклад engine](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/593/69)).

Тільки українські сторінки (напис не співпадає з рос. варіантом):

- Велобіг - 196 сторінок
- Біговел - 197 сторінок
- Біговелик - 6 сторінок
- Велоніг - 2 сторінки
- Велохід - 165 сторінок, частина результатів не про транспортний засіб а про "хресний велохід", наприклад "Велохід відбудеться з молебнями у храмах Полтави".
- Безпедальник - 37 сторінок (правда, деякі російські, бо не всі правильно пишуть приставку "бес-") (з фільтром Українська - 0)
- Безпедальний велосипед - 192 сторінки (з фільтром Українська - 160)
- Біговий велосипед - 190 сторінок, з них багато сторінок веломагазинів, до того ж із "неправильною" назвою, наприклад "гірський велосипед", тощо. При спробі зайти на таку сторінку цього словосполучення (навіть слова "біговий") немає.

Сторінки, включаючи російські (бо пишуться однаково)

- Велосамокат - 354 сторінки, фільтр "українською" повертає 170 сторінок. Причому велосамокат може бути наприклад таким: http://m.ua/jpg_zoom1/288441.jpg
- Велокат - 216 сторінок, фільтр "українською" повертає 193 сторінки.
- Велокетт - 191 сторінка, фільтр "українською" повертає 8 сторінок.
- Балансбайк - 320 сторінок, включаючи російські та болгарські, фільтр "українською" повертає 175 сторінок.
- Баланс-байк, баланс байк - 198 сторінок, включаючи російські та болгарські, фільтр "українською" повертає 132 сторнки.
- Ранбайк - 200 сторінок. Виявляється є фірма Runbike, що їх виготовляє, тому шукав "Ранбайк -Runbike", фільтр "українською" повертає 150 сторнки.
- Лауфрад - 173 сторінки. Так само походить від назви фірми Laufrad, фільтр "українською" повертає 27 сторінки.
- Велобалансир - 206 сторінок, фільтр "українською" повертає 69 сторінок.
- Баланс-велосипед - біля 200, фільтр "українською" повертає 110 сторінок. Але треба переглядати кожен результат, бо Гугл включає у список словосполучення "balance bike" навіть коли в налаштуваннях встановлено "сторінки з України" і "сторінки українською мовою".

Ще згадується варіант "балансир", але переважна більшість результатів - це різні гойдалки, скільки з них велосипеди - неможливо порахувати.

Як на мене, ця статистика не дає якогось однозначного лідера (назви, що також використовуються у російській мові дають в два рази вищий результат, але ж і сайтів російською мінімум у два рази більше). Можливо через те що багато інтернет-магазинів у назвах своїх товарів перераховують всі відомі їм варіанти щоб потрапити у результати пошуку.

Comment: А є ще "велоніг", але воно рідковживане.

Answer (score 0):

Англійською він називається *balance bike* тому українською можна було б назвати **балансовел** чи **рівноваговел.**

Comment: -1, перепрошую: будь ласка, вказуйте джерела.